# How to resize a VirtualBox vmdk file?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Although there are theoretically settings in the VirtualBox GUI that offer such a function, this is not yet supported in version 7 of Virtual Box.

Via terminal you can try an enlargement in the following way:

```
vboxmanage modifyhd my_source.vmdk --resize 16384
```

You will get the following error message:

```
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet!
```

How to resize a VirtualBox vmdk file?

Answer (score 0):

The size of a .vmdk file can be changed in at least the following two ways via VirtualBox:

Change via VirtualBox GUI:

- Copy the .vmdk file and select a .vdi file as the file type for the destination.
- Resize the .vdi file
- Open the .vdi file with Gparted and specify that you want to use the newly available memory when the window pops up (if you get a GParted message like this).
  Copy the .vdi file and select a .vmdk file as the file type for the target.

Change via terminal:

```
VBoxManage clonemedium "source.vmdk" "cloned.vdi" --format vdi
VBoxManage modifymedium "cloned.vdi" --resize 16384
VBoxManage clonemedium "cloned.vdi" "target.vmdk" --format vmdk
```

Open the .vdi file with Gparted and specify that you want to use the newly available memory when the window pops up. Copy the .vdi file and select a .vmdk file as the file type for the target (if you get a GParted message like this).